# selenium+pythonでファイルをアップロードするダイアログ操作

Tags: python, wordpress, selenium

皆様、お世話になります。

Seleniumのpythonを用いて、wordpressのメディアでファイルをアップロードしようと思っております。

1.ファイル選択ボタンを押す
2.ファイル選択ダイアログボタンが開く
3.ファイル名をダイアログ上でファイル名を入力
4.ダイアログのファイルを「開く」を押す

上記1~2まではできるのですが、3と4ができません。
つまり、ダイアログを開いた後、ダイアログの操作が全くできていません。
以下のコードの問題点についてご指導をお願いします。

```
element = browser.find_element_by_id("__wp-uploader-id-1")
element.click()
element.send_keys(r'.\tokyo_view.png')
element.click()
```

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ [Upload Image on WordPress Website Using Python Selenium](https://medium.com/dreamcatcher-its-blog/upload-image-on-wordpress-website-using-python-selenium-5fcf84eb9f82), [How to upload files in a WordPress post using Selenium Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42974673/9014308), [PythonからWordpressに自動投稿するスクリプトを作りました。](https://review-of-my-life.blogspot.com/2017/11/python-wordpress.html)

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございました！答えは「動的なxpath」を作ることにあったんですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイル名を入力しようとしている要素はおそらく、
OSレベルのポップアップのためseleniumでは操作できません。

別の方法ですが、下記ページを参考にしたらできました。
https://www.dafuku.com/2014/12/selenium-file-upload.html